# Logic app blob trigger retry policy not working for 503 error

Tags: triggers, blob, azure-logic-apps, retrypolicy

I have created a logic app consumption which use blob trigger when a new blob added to container it will trigger. Im using set of action and in that action if I face any error the trigger retry is not working. I tried with default and fixed interval and exponential not working any of it . I tried to mock 503 and connection time out for this as I'm facing this in my original implementation. As per the notes mentioned under the retry policy 408, 503 and connection error it should retry but none of the retry working as expected...

1. When a blob is added or modified (properties only) trigger
2. Compose action
   3.http action (mocking 503 and connection time out)
3. Delete blob action

Any idea what's happening wrong in this??? Is it latest bug from Microsoft???

Used user assigned managed identity for blob access.
Tried to reproduce 503 error and connection time out in http action.. tried changing trigger retry policy to default, fixed interval and exponential still nothing works. Trigger retry not happening